# How to make multiple connections on codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

how do I make multiple database connections in codeigniter 3 based on input variables? for example one controller has one database, so each controller has a different database. because if you change it from the database.php configuration, the database name will be constant, not adjusting to the controller. please for the solution. thank you.

Comment: Please refer this link - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html?highlight=database#connecting-to-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

Generally we set our database information in "application/config/database.php". If you are using multiple database, you need to set them also in "application/config/database.php".

Generally we set our default database like :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "main_db";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Now if you want to add another databasem you can set it in a new array - let's call it 'db1'. And set it in "application/config/database.php" as follows :

```
$db['db1']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['db1']['username'] = "root";
$db['db1']['password'] = "";
$db['db1']['database'] = "db1";
$db['db1']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['db1']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['db1']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db1']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['db1']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db1']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['db1']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['db1']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['db1']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['db1']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db1']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Now if you want to use db1 in a method, use it this way :

```
function example_method()
{
    $db1 = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE);
    $query = $db1->select(*')->get('users');
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but the problem is I have 10 databases for each different controller. Do all databases need to be input into a new array in the database.php configuration? if so, of course it will be quite troublesome in the future when the database grows even more